# golang return a function variables got stucked using gin

Tags: go, go-gin

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64

using golang:1.19.5-bullseye on ubuntu:20.04
```

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

```
$ go env

GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/code/mlflow/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build4126953061=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

#### What did you do?

**return a function variable stucked, but success in others **
I'm not sure whether this is golang's bug,  just reporting for a luck

my code:

```
apis.GET("/:ns/workspaces", middle.LoginRequired, route.GH(s.listWorkspaces))
...
func GH(fn func(c *gin.Context) http.HandlerFunc) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        logrus.Info("processing handler")
        replyer := fn(c)
        logrus.Info("replyer processing")
        replyer(c.Writer, c.Request)
        logrus.Info("replyer done")
    }
}
// handler:
func (s *Server) listWorkspaces(c *gin.Context) http.HandlerFunc {
    //...
    cnn, err := s.Conn(ctx)
    logrus.Info(1)
    // err = merr.Wrap(nil, 2333, "ops...")
    if err != nil {
        return route.Err(err)
    }
    defer cnn.Close()
    logrus.Info(2)

    items, total, err := models.SearchWorkspaces(ctx, cnn, *searchUnity)
    err = merr.Wrap(nil, 2333, "ops...")
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Info("2.1, err: %#v", err)
        replyer := route.Err(err)
        return replyer
    }
    logrus.Info(3)

func Err(err error) http.HandlerFunc {
    logrus.Infof("at reply-Wrapper-Err, err: %#v", err)
    replyer := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        logrus.Infof("in replyer...")
         //...
         responser(w, r)
    }
    logrus.Infof("reply-Wrapper-Err end")
    return replyer
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

code should execute success or failed, or panic.
and logs should print in this orders:

#### What did you see instead?

the code always stucked at  the `return replyer` line
but success in other return line.
when I uncomment the

```
// err = merr.Wrap(nil, 2333, "ops...")
```

before  the `return route.Err(err)` line, it runs well

I tried debug using dlv, got stucked too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecG6O.png)

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve here with this code ? Are you trying to accept a function inside a handler and then send the response out ? Or are you accepting a handler function within a handler ? I think the second approach is not quite right. You can use middlewares if you want common functionality. Responses should always be sent out with `ctx.JSON` or similar methods on the gin context. You don't need to use the underlying response writers.